# True/False $(f(x))^2 = x^2$

Tags: calculus, functions

There exists a non-constant function $f$ such that $(f(x))^2 = x^2$.  If your answer is true, then give ALL of the functions that satisfy this condition.  If the answer is false, explain.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: $x$ is a non-constant function.

Answer (score 7):

There are an uncountable number
of such functions.

Let
$g(x) = x$
and 
$h(x) = -x$.
Then both $g$ and $h$
satisfy
$(f(x))^2 = x^2$
on the reals.

Let
$S$ be any subset of the reals.
Define $f$ by
$f(x) = g(x)$ if $x \in S$
and
$f(x) = h(x)$ if $x \not\in S$.

Then $(f(x))^2 = x^2$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
but $f$ is not nice.

Actually,
the number of possible such functions
is the number of subsets of the reals,
which is a lot.

I think that these are all the
possible functions.
No proof offered,

Comment: seems clear -- very nice

Answer (score 1):

Hint, consider these few functions:

- $f(x)=x$
- $f(x)=-x$
- $f(x)=|x|$
- $f(x)=-|x|$

(These are a pair of similar functions in terms of values, but could they be considered different in some other way.)

- $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$
- $f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2}$

I imagine taking the $n$th root of $x^n$ with various sign inversions would also be a possible function f though these would be equivalent functions though how to prove that is an open question along with various combinations of these functions as one could define f(x) in a piece-meal fashion as there isn't a requirement for f to be continuous.

Comment: Please explain how your third example differs from your fifth one.

Comment: ${\sqrt{x}}^2 = |x|$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = x$

Comment: @Bonnaduck, you are mistaken: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.  $(\sqrt{x})^2$, however, is not defined for negative $x$.

Comment: @vadim123, you're right, got those mixed up. Why would it not be defined for negative $x$? $(\sqrt{-3})^2 = (\sqrt{3})^2 i^2 = -3$.

Comment: The values of f don't differ.  However, what makes for different functions isn't stated in the question.

Comment: @Bonnaduck, because if you do that then one can prove $1=-1$ by the following $1=\sqrt{1^2}=\sqrt{-1^2}=i^2=-1$, as $1=-1*-1$

Comment: @JBKing The property does not hold for two negative numbers. It does, however, if one of the numbers is positive.

Comment: @Bonnaduck, what if I have 4 negative numbers?  I can always add another 1 to the product that could be broken down into a product of two -1s or add another 1 which is positive to the product without changing its value.

Comment: @JBKing Sure you can. But it does not change the fact that $(\sqrt{-1*a})^2=(\sqrt{-1})^2(\sqrt{a})^2=-a$ for any nonnegative real number $a$. You can throw in any even amount of -1s under the radical, and the result will hold so long as you multiply the all -1s before splitting the radical.

Answer (score 1):

Marty Cohen gave a complete characterization of all such functions; my small contribution is to describe the continuous ones.  Since $f(x)\in\{x,-x\}$ for all $x$ (as shown by other solutions), it can only switch from one to the other (and remain continuous) at $0$.  Hence the complete list has just four:

$$f(x)=x, f(x)=-x, f(x)=|x|, f(x)=-|x|$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to have $f(x)^2=x^2$ which implies $$f(x)^2-x^2=0 $$that is $$\big(f(x)-x\big)\big(f(x)+x)=0$$ so $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$ .

Comment: What if f is the absolute value function?  Doesn't it also work?